# Fetch Record Assets in CloudKit Using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am new to CloudKit and I am having trouble connecting the assets in my database to the ImageView and TextView in my app. In my CloudKit database, under record types, I created a record named "Companies". I then went to Public Data->Default Zone and then created a new instance of the record called "myCompany". In "myCompany" I have two assets, an image and a .txt file. I want to connect those assets to my app. I am not sure if I need to use CKQuery or what is the best approach. Any advice would be much appreciated. Below is what I have so far. Feel free to give feedback of what I have or if there's a better way, I would love to know. Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class LearnViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var theImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var theText: UITextView!


let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Companies" )

var image: UIImage!

let database =  CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase


func loadCoverPhoto(completion:(photo: UIImage!) -> ()) {
    dispatch_async(
        dispatch_get_global_queue(
            DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)){
                var image: UIImage!
                let coverPhoto = self.myRecord.objectForKey("Picture") as CKAsset!
                if let asset = coverPhoto {

                    if let url = asset.fileURL {
                        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path!)!

                        image = UIImage(data: imageData) 
                    }
                }

                completion(photo: image)
    }
}


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadCoverPhoto() { photo in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.theImage.image = photo
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get the record directly if you know the recordId by performing a fetch like:

```
database.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: recordId), completionHandler: {record, error in
```

Or if you don't know the ID you should query for the record with something like the code below. just create the right NSPredicate. A query can return more than 1 record.

```
var query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
var operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
operation.recordFetchedBlock = { record in
    // is this your record...
}
operation.queryCompletionBlock = { cursor, error in
    self.handleCallback(error, errorHandler: {errorHandler(error: error)}, completionHandler: {
        // ready fetching records
        })
}
operation.resultsLimit = CKQueryOperationMaximumResults;
database.addOperation(operation)
```

In your case when using the fetchRecordWithID option the code would look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    database.fetchRecordWithID(CKRecordID(recordName: recordId), completionHandler: {record, error in
        self.myRecord = record
        loadCoverPhoto() { photo in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.theImage.image = photo
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I integrate the first option in my current code? I am confused as how to use fetchRecordWithID. I do know the specific ID.

Comment: I added sample code to the answer. You do have to replace the recordId with the correct ID

Comment: and recordID would simply be a string?

Comment: yes, that would be something like "C6F204D2-2F40-481F-926A-F2DF0863A7B8"

Comment: You do have to be careful with fixed recordID's in your code. When you move to production the data from development will not be migrated. You will have to create a new record which will also get a new recordID

Comment: I am confused because with let myRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Companies" ) and my current code, shouldn't I be getting access to my assets and being able to connect them to my ImageView? I don't understand why I would need the ID or to query when I already know the name via recordType?

Comment: Is there something in my code that's wrong so as to explain why my image on CloudKit isn't showing up on my app? I do greatly appreciate your responses but I am confused as to how it all ties together.

Comment: you could compare recordType to a table. So you could have multiple Companies. You need to fetch the specific company record from CloudKit. You could get one using the recordID or you could query the Companies by using a CKQuery

Comment: I got it to work using CKQuery. Thank you for your help. I have one more question. In the CloudKit database, I create a record under Record Types called "Companies". Now, under Public->Default Zone I create an instance of "Companies" called "Apple". How do I access "Apple" if I have other companies. I simply have this 
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Companies", predicate: predicate)

Comment: You can do all sorts of filtering with NSPredicate. You could for instance run a query like NSPredicate(format: "Company = %@", selectCompany)

Comment: What if instead of bringing back 2 specific records you wanted to append an array from multiple records?  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: If you want to search for an array of companies, then you could use a predicate like NSPredicate(format: "Company in %@", [selectCompany])