# CKAsset won't show in tableview image

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiimage, cloudkit

I have an optional image in the cloudkit DB(checked DB and the image is there in cases where I added it in my testing). I have created a class that initializes the record fields into variables I use in my tableview. I have a custom cell as well. But the image won't display in my custom tableview cell. I don't know if having an optional image in a tableview image is causing a problem or if there's an issue with my code/settings in cloudkit.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck for over a week and there's little to nothing online about this.

Here's my class code:

```
var feedResults = [UserPosts]()

class UserPosts {

var record: CKRecord
var description: String
var username: String
//var image: CKAsset? // tried also initializing the CKAsset separately
var postPic: UIImage?


init(record: CKRecord) {

    self.record = record
    self.description = record.objectForKey("description") as String
    self.username = record.objectForKey("username") as String
   // self.image = record.objectForKey("postPic") as? CKAsset


    if var pic = record.objectForKey("postPic") as CKAsset! {

           self.postPic = UIImage(contentsOfFile: pic.fileURL.path!)

            // below is the other way I've seen it done.
               // var url = pic.fileURL!
               // var imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path!)
              // self.postPic = UIImage(data: imageData!)

    }
}
```

}

Here's my tableview code:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

    let record = feedResults[indexPath.row]
    cell.postDescription.text = record.description
    cell.userName.text = record.username

    if record.postPic != nil {

         cell.postPic.image = record.postPic!

    }

    return cell
}
```

Also I've seen a couple ways of pulling a CKAsset into a UIImage. The first way, is how I saw Apple do it in their CloudKitAtlas project. Although I'm not well versed in Obj-C, I think I followed it correctly - [CloudKitAtlas Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Listings/CloudKitAtlas_AAPLCKAssetViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014599-CloudKitAtlas_AAPLCKAssetViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6)

I've also seen it done using NSData(contentOFFile:) and UIImage(data:), as shown in this post here: [SO CKAsset Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206955/fetch-record-assets-in-cloudkit-using-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it without the .paths and using contentsOfURL. This is how I do this (within your if for the CKAsset):

```
         if var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: pic!.fileURL) {
            self.postPic =  UIImage(data: data!)!
        }
```

And besides that... You do a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but don't check if it returns nil. You should create a new cell instance If it was nil

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got this error on the first line (if pic != nil), but not sure what it means - "Cannot invoke != with an argument of list type (@|CKAsset, NIlLiteralConvertible).

Comment: I tried the following code, which got rid of error, but the pics still don't show in tableview. ( and I initialized the class variable=image as CKAsset): 

`if record.objectForKey("postPic") != nil {
            
            self.image = record.objectForKey("postPic") as CKAsset!

            if image != nil {
                
                var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: image!.fileURL)

                if data != nil {

                    self.postPic =  UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
        }`

Comment: Ah... sorry... Did not notice the 'if var pic..' construction. Of course you could then just skip the 'if pic != nil' check.

Comment: Could it be that the CKAsset is not retrieved yet before you show the table? When the records with the assets are returned you could do a .reloadData on the tableView.

Comment: I think I have the code you suggest, but it's still not pulling in the pics. I wonder if something else is wrong.  Any other ideas? Thanks again!
`  if var pic = record.objectForKey("postPic") as CKAsset! {
            
                    if var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: pic.fileURL) {
                        self.postPic =  UIImage(data: data)!
                    }
             }`

Comment: Oh, I just saw your 2nd comment. I do have a reloadData in the completion block already. I wonder what else I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I call my DB query func in the viewDidLoad method of the view controller. And the completion block contains the reloadData method.  Does this sound right?

Comment: instead of the viewDidLoad try the viewDidAppear. It could happen that the  query returns it's data and the .ReloadData is called before your .xib is bound to your code. Try setting a breakpoint at the line 'cell.postPic.image = record.postPic!' If it's not called, then you still do not have the data.

Comment: I tried putting in viewDidAppear, and it didn't help. Also, I did a break point on the initialization line of the var postPic, as well as the cell.postPic.image, and in both cases, the value is nil. I must be missing something. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I found my error in the DB query code! Thanks for suggesting the breakpoint. That made me dig deeper into code I wrote a while back. In my query I used the property "desiredKeys" and had left out the image field because I hadn't learned how to save the image to the DB yet.And your code works now for pulling in the image. I'm sorry about this. Feel silly I didn't check that code thoroughly first. Thanks again so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can display the image from the CKAsset like this:

```
    var img = record.valueForKey("Picture") as? CKAsset
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img!.fileURL.path!)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Turned out my code above works, but I messed up in my DB query.  I believe your code would work if I didn't have an optional image in the DB.  There are a few ways I could have done it, but I think the way I have my above code is the most succinct.  And Edwin's code also works within my classes "if statement." Thanks for responding!