# Cannot assign value of type CKAsset to type UIImage

Tags: swift, image, uitableview, cloudkit

When setting the image of my table cell to my "Picture" I am greeted with the error in this code.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "foodcell") as! FoodTableCell
    let restaurant: CKRecord = restaurantArrayList[indexPath.row]
    cell.name?.text = restaurant.value(forKey: "Name") as? String


    cell.picture?.image = restaurant.value(forKey: "Picture") as? CKAsset
    //the error is here ^
    return cell
```

How would I go about successfully setting up my "Picture" key as the image in my cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CKAsset won't show in tableview image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290142/ckasset-wont-show-in-tableview-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CKAsset` isn't an image format, but more like a wrapper for a URL that's pointing to an asset.

Assuming that your `restaurant` record does have an asset under the key "Picture":

```
let asset = resturaunt["picture"] as! CKAsset
// 'resturaunt["picture"]' is just another way of writing 'restaurant.value(forKey: "Picture")'

let data = try! Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)
// this contains the binary data from the asset url

let image = UIImage(date: data)
// now make an image with that binary data
```

There are a lot of forced unwrapped optionals happening above, the safer approach you'll probably want to take is like this:

```
if let asset = resturaunt["picture"] as? CKAsset, 
   let data = try? Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL) {

    cell.picture?.image = UIImage(date: data)
}
```

**use of try?**

`Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL)` might throw an error that you need to recover from so you need to use the `try` keyword and manage the possible error it might throw.

Swift 3 added `do-try-catch` syntax for error handling that takes this general form:

```
do {
  // statements that might throw an error need to be called within here
  try callSomeMethodThatMightThrow()
  let value = try callMethodReturnValueMightThrow()
}
catch {
  // statements in this block will get called if an error was encountered
}
```

`try?` is a shorthand way to deal with this which avoids the do-catch syntax. When you use it, you're saying, "if an error occurs, then assign the value to `nil`"

There's a more detailed post here explaining in more detail about use of `try`, `try?` and also `try!` https://cocoacasts.com/error-handling-in-swift-with-the-try-keyword/

Comment: You're a beautiful person, haha. The code is working perfectly. Both sections of code are also appreciated to have the complete "picture" of the program.

Comment: Sorry, for the additional response. While the code is just what I needed (and again, thank you!), would you mind explaining the "let data = try! Data(contentsOf: asset.fileURL" line of code? I'm looking to understanding the basics of it all and just can't seem to wrap my head around this line. Any response would be appreciated!

Comment: No problem! I added some more detail to the answer, and also a link that does a good job of explaining the options